Help Needed: Repairing Collapsed Wall in 1800s Root Cellar
We have a cottage in Småland that dates back to the mid-1800s. Attached to the house is a root cellar with one wall that has collapsed, with the stones falling into a heap. It started when we noticed a hole next to one of the doors, and when we looked down, a few stones had fallen in. When we tried to investigate the hole, the entire wall collapsed.
The collapsed wall is in the ”room” with the stairs, and beyond this is another room, which is the actual root cellar. We've checked with our insurance company, and unfortunately, they don't cover this damage, so we need to address it ourselves as soon as possible, considering the water ingress and the risk of further collapse.
The root cellar is located beneath the kitchen, and to the right of the collapsed wall is the entrance to the house (small room). Currently, there is no immediate risk of more collapse, but it is naturally a concern.
The question now is how to proceed with the repair? First, we need to remove the fallen stones, but what next? Trying to restack the stones might be challenging, and we’re unsure if it’s even necessary. We considered removing the remaining stones from this wall and instead securing the stones inside (under the entrance) with concrete/mortar. Do you have any other suggestions on how we might resolve this?
Pictures can be found here: https://postimg.cc/gallery/WZWMwLM
Thanks!

Hire a pro. You can not afford to have the foundation fail
